# deleted /etc/environment file by accident

Tags: delete, etc, environment

I deleted the `/etc/environment` file by accident. Is it important? What does it do? How can I recover it?

I saw another post saying most of the time the file has the same generic line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Is this true, or should I make my own line for the new file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct but you are missing "snap". Mine shows this:

```
~$ more /etc/environment
 PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

Copy either your, mine, or if someone else posts one theirs into into `/etc/environment`. It is a text file so feel free to edit it; the file is owned by `root` so do a `sudo -i` before editing it.

Comment: Is it an important file? what happens if I don't have it?

Comment: depends on your system. `grep -l pam_env /etc/pam.d/*` shows all procedures that depend on it.